# What is the PnP Equivalent of Set-SPOSiteGroup

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, pnp

I'm trying to programmatically change the default permission level from Edit to Contribute on the Members group.

```
connect-sposervice https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com

Set-SPOSiteGroup -Site https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/EQD96 -identity "Projects Members" -PermissionLevelsToRemove "Edit" -PermissionLevelsToAdd "Contribute"
```

When using PnP cmdlets, it doesn't prompt me to login every time. Is there a known equivalent of this cmdlet?

```
Set-SPOSiteGroup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `Set-PnPGroup`

**Example: Change Group Owner using PnP PowerShell**

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://crescenttech.sharepoint.com/Sales"
$GroupName="Sales Portal Members"
#Group owner variable: Can be existing group or user account Email
$GroupOwner = "Sales Portal Owners" #or Salaudeen@Crescent.com

#Connect PNP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

#Set Group Owner
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $GroupName -Owner $GroupOwner
```

For details please refer the below URL :

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/05/sharepoint-online-change-group-owner-using-powershell.html?m=1

Comment: Yes, except I had to use the switch -AddRole & -RemoveRole

Answer (score 0):

[Set-PnPGroup](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpgroup?view=sharepoint-ps) would be the equivalent.